# Get a list of values from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, and I need to get a list of the values from a given key from the dictionary (all the dictionaries have those same key).

For example, I have:

```
l = [ { "key": 1, "Val1": 'val1 from element 1', "Val2": 'val2 from element 1' }, 
      { "key": 2, "Val1": 'val1 from element 2', "Val2": 'val2 from element 2' }, 
      { "key": 3, "Val1": 'val1 from element 3', "Val2": 'val2 from element 3' } ]
```

I need to get 1, 2, 3.

Of course, I can get it with:

```
v=[]
for i in l:
    v.append(i['key'])
```

But I would like to get a nicer way to do so.

Comment: do they all definitely have the key?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (if you're sure every dictionary has the key):

```
In [10]: [d['key'] for d in l]
Out[10]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Otherwise you'll need to check for existence first:

```
In [11]: [d['key'] for d in l if 'key' in d]
Out[11]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: One line... Or less ;)

Comment: That's what I was looking for, doing it on a single line. Will test it, thank you.