# generate list from values of certain field in list of objects

Tags: python

How would I generate a list of values of a certain field of objects in a list?

Given the list of objects:

```
[ {name: "Joe", group: 1}, {name: "Kirk", group: 2}, {name: "Bob", group: 1}]
```

I want to generate list of the name field values:

```
["Joe", "Kirk", "Bob"]
```

The built-in `filter()` function seems to come close, but it will return the entire objects themselves.

I'd like a clean, one line solution such as:

```
filterLikeFunc(function(obj){return obj.name}, mylist)
```

Sorry, I know that's c syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of values from a list of dictionaries in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040875/get-a-list-of-values-from-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python)

Comment: I'm not working with a dictionary, but I'll see if I can adapt that Q's answer.

Comment: One line.. a good use-case for `list comprehension`

Comment: I see. Both `map` and  `list comprehensions` are new to me. Great to be introduced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension approach you get:

```
objects = [{'group': 1, 'name': 'Joe'}, {'group': 2, 'name': 'Kirk'}, {'group': 1, 'name': 'Bob'}]
names = [i["name"] for i in objects]
```

For a good intro to list comprehensions, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: If you're an experienced programmer checking out Python, you'll probably enjoy the book Dive into Python (www.diveintopython.net).

Answer (score 3):

Just replace [**filter**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) built-in function with [**map**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) built-in function.

And use [get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068349/understanding-get-method-in-python) function which will not give you key error in the absence of that particular key to get value for `name` key.

```
data = [{'name': "Joe", 'group': 1}, {'name': "Kirk", 'group': 2}, {'name': "Bob", 'group': 1}]

print map(lambda x: x.get('name'), data)
```

In Python 3.x

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x.get('name'), data)))
```

Results:

```
['Joe', 'Kirk', 'Bob']
```

---

Using [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
print [each.get('name') for each in data]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over your list of dicts and pick out the `name` value and put them in a list.

```
x = [ {'name': "Joe", 'group': 1}, {'name': "Kirk", 'group': 2}, {'name': "Bob", 'group': 1}]

y = [y['name'] for y in x]

print(y)
```