# Get the value of particular key from all dictionaries Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary like this,

```
a = [{'SegmentName': 'FICO High', 'CohortMonthYear': '01-01-2015', 'DriverValue': '0.921996823602789',
      'MonthsOnBooks': '1',
      'CohortQuarterYear': 'Q1 2015', 'PortfolioId': '55dc0e48c95a8a1a2ffb836e', 'DriverName': 'Active rate'},
     {'SegmentName': 'FICO High', 'CohortMonthYear': '01-01-2015', 'DriverValue': '0.9123400335106416',
      'MonthsOnBooks': '2', 'CohortQuarterYear': 'Q1 2015', 'PortfolioId': ('55dc0e48c95a8a1a2ffb836e'),
      'DriverName': 'Active rate'},
     {'SegmentName': 'FICO High', 'CohortMonthYear': '01-01-2015', 'DriverValue': '0.9024207736261439',
      'MonthsOnBooks': '3', 'CohortQuarterYear': 'Q1 2015', 'PortfolioId': ('55dc0e48c95a8a1a2ffb836e'),
      'DriverName': 'Active rate'},
     {'SegmentName': 'FICO High', 'CohortMonthYear': '01-01-2015', 'DriverValue': '0.889915542915732',
      'MonthsOnBooks': '4',
      'CohortQuarterYear': 'Q1 2015', 'PortfolioId': ('55dc0e48c95a8a1a2ffb836e'), 'DriverName': 'Active rate'},
     {'SegmentName': 'FICO High', 'CohortMonthYear': '01-01-2015', 'DriverValue': '0.8806580068608421',
      'MonthsOnBooks': '5', 'CohortQuarterYear': 'Q1 2015', 'PortfolioId': ('55dc0e48c95a8a1a2ffb836e'),
      'DriverName': 'Active rate'},
     {'SegmentName': 'FICO High', 'CohortMonthYear': '02-01-2015', 'DriverValue': '0.9458702933667549',
      'MonthsOnBooks': '1', 'CohortQuarterYear': 'Q1 2015', 'PortfolioId': ('55dc0e48c95a8a1a2ffb836e'),
      'DriverName': 'Active rate'},
     {'SegmentName': 'FICO High', 'CohortMonthYear': '02-01-2015', 'DriverValue': '0.9335318149106486',
      'MonthsOnBooks': '2', 'CohortQuarterYear': 'Q1 2015', 'PortfolioId': ('55dc0e48c95a8a1a2ffb836e'),
      'DriverName': 'Active rate'},
     {'SegmentName': 'FICO High', 'CohortMonthYear': '02-01-2015', 'DriverValue': '0.9225337221412799',
      'MonthsOnBooks': '3', 'CohortQuarterYear': 'Q1 2015', 'PortfolioId': ('55dc0e48c95a8a1a2ffb836e'),
      'DriverName': 'Active rate'},
     {'SegmentName': 'FICO High', 'CohortMonthYear': '02-01-2015', 'DriverValue': '0.9109689291572624',
      'MonthsOnBooks': '4', 'CohortQuarterYear': 'Q1 2015', 'PortfolioId': ('55dc0e48c95a8a1a2ffb836e'),
      'DriverName': 'Active rate'},
     {'SegmentName': 'FICO High', 'CohortMonthYear': '03-01-2015', 'DriverValue': '0.9092991755453589',
      'MonthsOnBooks': '1', 'CohortQuarterYear': 'Q1 2015', 'PortfolioId': ('55dc0e48c95a8a1a2ffb836e'),
      'DriverName': 'Active rate'},
     {'SegmentName': 'FICO High', 'CohortMonthYear': '03-01-2015', 'DriverValue': '0.8988101317456371',
      'MonthsOnBooks': '2', 'CohortQuarterYear': 'Q1 2015', 'PortfolioId': ('55dc0e48c95a8a1a2ffb836e'),
      'DriverName': 'Active rate'},
     {'SegmentName': 'FICO High', 'CohortMonthYear': '03-01-2015', 'DriverValue': '0.8860809446836048',
      'MonthsOnBooks': '3', 'CohortQuarterYear': 'Q1 2015', 'PortfolioId': ('55dc0e48c95a8a1a2ffb836e'),
      'DriverName': 'Active rate'},
     {'SegmentName': 'FICO High', 'CohortMonthYear': '04-01-2015', 'DriverValue': '0.9471495415096017',
      'MonthsOnBooks': '1', 'CohortQuarterYear': 'Q2 2015', 'PortfolioId': ('55dc0e48c95a8a1a2ffb836e'),
      'DriverName': 'Active rate'},
     {'SegmentName': 'FICO High', 'CohortMonthYear': '04-01-2015', 'DriverValue': '0.9364314248533585',
      'MonthsOnBooks': '2', 'CohortQuarterYear': 'Q2 2015', 'PortfolioId': ('55dc0e48c95a8a1a2ffb836e'),
      'DriverName': 'Active rate'},
     {'SegmentName': 'FICO High', 'CohortMonthYear': '05-01-2015', 'DriverValue': '0.9344317261744861',
      'MonthsOnBooks': '1', 'CohortQuarterYear': 'Q2 2015', 'PortfolioId': ('55dc0e48c95a8a1a2ffb836e'),
      'DriverName': 'Active rate'}]
```

I need to iterate over the list of dictionaries and get the DriverValue of all dictionary without repeating the SegmentName and DriverName and PortfolioId.

This is my code so far,

```
mm = []
for i in a:
    ss = {'DriverName': i['DriverName'], 'SegmentName': i['SegmentName'], 'PortfolioId': i['PortfolioId'],
          'DriverValue': []}

    if all([i['DriverName'] == 'DriverName' and i['SegmentName'] == 'SegmentName']):
        ss['DriverValue'].append(i['DriverValue'])

    mm.append(ss)

print(mm)
```

The DriverValue is always empty in the list. Where I am doing wrong?

Sample Output:

```
{
    "PortfolioId" : ("55d4247b119a612af00eff4b"),
    "DriverName" : "Active rate",
    "SampleData" : [ 
        30, 
        24, 
        6, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9, 
        9
    ]
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of values from a list of dictionaries in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25040875/2301450)?

Comment: what do you think, the `if`-condition is doing?

Comment: please don't dump code into your questions - limiting the list of dicts to 4-5 entries would have been enough to illustrate your question

Comment: [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) is meant to operate on a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Theres probably a more elegant approach to this, but this will get you the key value pairs for each occurrence of the "drivervalue" key in the list of dictionaries, and then store the values in your list mm:

```
mm = []
for b in a:
    for key,value in b.items():
        if key == "DriverValue":
            mm.append(value)
```

Just played around and another approach is:

```
p = [d['DriverValue'] for d in a]
```

Where p will be a list of the values. Hope this helps.